# dual representation -- show that it actually is a linear representation in the dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $\rho : G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ be a linear representation in $V$.

Show that $\rho^* : G \to \mathrm{GL}(V^*)$ with $\rho^*(g)(f) = f \circ \rho(g^{-1})$ is a linear representation on $V^*$.

---

So I try to show, that it is a homomorphism starting with

$\rho^*(gh)(f) = f \circ \rho((gh)^{-1}) = f \circ \rho(h^{-1}) \circ \rho(g^{-1})$

But I don't get to: $\rho^*(g)(f) \circ \rho^*(h)(f)$

I think I got stupidly stuck, maybe someone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting your last line: after all, $$f\circ \rho(h^{-1})\circ \rho(g^{-1})
= \big(f\circ \rho(h^{-1})\big)\circ \rho(g^{-1})
= \big(\rho^*(h)f\big)\circ \rho(g^{-1})
= \rho^*(g)\big(\rho^*(h)f\big)
$$
That is, you were essentially done, but misjudged that last little bit of rearrangement.

Comment: embarrassing..sorry for wasting time :-(

Comment: @numaaa, I have made the same mistake many times in my life...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\rho^\ast(gh)$ sends $f\mapsto f\circ\rho(h^{-1})\circ\rho(g^{-1})$. On the other hand, $\rho^\ast g\circ\rho^\ast h$ sends $f$ to
$$
(\rho^\ast g\circ\rho^\ast h)(f)=(\rho^\ast g)((\rho^\ast h)(f))=(\rho^\ast g)(f\circ\rho(h^{-1}))=f\circ\rho(h^{-1})\circ\rho(g^{-1}).
$$
So you are done.